# Codimension of Effective CD

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

An effective Cartier Divisor $D$ of a integer Scheme $X$ is associated to a set of tuple $\{(U_i, f_i)\}$ where $U_i$ prove a affine covering of $X$ and $f_i \in \Gamma(U_i, \mathcal{O}_X)$ are the regular local sections. These a defining in invertible ideal sheaf $\rho$ on $X$. Thus I can interpret the Cartier Divisor $D$ as support the quotient ideal $\mathcal{O}_X / \rho$.

My question is why has $D$ codimension $1$?

My ideas: As I know the codimenion of a subscheme is defined by $\operatorname{codim}(D,X) = \inf \{ \dim \mathcal{O}_{D,y} \mid y\in D \}$ (is it the right definition?)

Futhermore, because $D$ arises from $\mathcal{O}_X / \rho$ it's stalks are of the shape $\mathcal{O}_{D, y} =\mathcal{O}_{X, y} / (f)$ for a regular $f$.
Applying Krull's Principle Ideal Theorem I get only the unequality $1 \ge dim(\mathcal{O}_{D,y})$, but how to get the equality?

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of codimension is wrong; you should be looking at $\mathcal{O}_{X,y}$, not $\mathcal{O}_{D,y}$.  If $\mathcal{O}_{X,y}$ is $0$-dimensional, that means $y$ is the generic point of $X$, corresponding to the trivial ideal $\{0\}$ on any affine open subset.  Since each $f_i$ is required to be nonzero, it cannot vanish at the generic point of $X$, so the generic point cannot be in $D$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I have a futher question: With your argument we get $codim(D,X) \ge 1$. Also, using Krull again, we get $1 \ge dim(\mathcal{O}_{X,y})-1 = dim(\mathcal{O}_{D,y})$. But this does provide the possiblities that $dim(\mathcal{O}_{X,y})$ equals $2$ or $1$, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't know where you're getting $1 \ge dim(\mathcal{O}_{X,y})-1$ from.  Why are you subtracting 1?

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that because that $D$ is a support we have $y \in D$ is the same as $f_i \in m_y$. I used here a consequence of KPI Theorem that for every $f \in m_R$ we have $dim(R/{fR}) \ge dim(R)-1$ wich is a equality if $f$ isn't contained in any minimal prime ideal. Because $X$ integer and $f$ regular this automatically holds, doesn't it?

Comment: OK, so $dim(\mathcal{O}_{X,y})-1 = dim(\mathcal{O}_{D,y})$.  But I have no idea where you get the $1\geq$ at the start from.  You want to minimize these dimensions, so you can choose $y$ such that $dim(\mathcal{O}_{D,y})=0$ (just take a minimal prime of the ring corresponding to $D$ on any affine open).

Comment: That means finding a prime ideal with property be minimal containing $f$... Can I find all time someone in this case? The problem is that the affine open sets in general don't correspond to Artinian rings ...

Comment: Any nonzero ring has a minimal prime ideal by Zorn's lemma, since an intersection of a chain of prime ideals is prime.

Comment: In addition: The $1 \ge dim(\mathcal{O}_{D,y})$ comes again from KPI. By the way: In your second comment it seemed that you didn't needed the unequality between the stalk dimensions as I posted above. In which do you conclude that $codim(D,X)=1$ holds. I'm quite currious how you see this without explicitly using the KPI Theorem.

Comment: ...$1 \ge dim(\mathcal{O}_{D,y})$ if $y$ corresponds to a minimal prime ideal containing $f$! Sorry for embezzling inportatant information :)

Comment: KPI tells you $1\geq dim(\mathcal{O}_{X,y})$ for $y$ a minimal prime ideal containing $f$, not $1\geq\dim(\mathcal{O}_{D,y})$.  I didn't mean to imply you can do this without KPI, but the inequality you wrote is not what KPI says...